# In QML, I cannot get a shortcut for a CheckBox

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

In the following QML menu, I can get the shortcut for "File" and "New", but not for "Auto Save":

```
menuBar: MenuBar {
    Menu {
        title: qsTr("&File")
        Action { text: qsTr("&New...") }
        CheckBox {
           id: autoSaveButton
           checked: true
           text: qsTr("&Auto Save")
           action: autoSaveAction
        }
}
```

Is the reason the fact that a CheckBox behaves differently from an Action?

I tried to move the CheckBox out of the menu, on the toolbar, with no improvement.

Qt version: 6.4

Comment: I guess that you need to set the `text` in your `autoSaveAction`. From https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-controls2-action.html#details Buttons and menu items get their text and icon from the action by default.

Comment: Whilst Action can be used as a child as Menu, is there any reason why you're not using either MenuItem or ToolButton? You'll also note that CheckBox itself is not an action, but as @iam_peter answers below the checkable property can be set on Action and MenuItem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No need for a `CheckBox` you can use an `Action` or a `MenuItem` and set the `checkable` property to `true`. A bit strange is that I needed to toggle the `checked` property manually in the `onToggled` or `onTriggered` handler, otherwise the `checked` of both `MenuItem` and `Action` wouldn't change automatically when using the shortcut even though toggled and triggered are called. But it does when clicking on the menu item.

```
menuBar: MenuBar {
    Menu {
        title: qsTr("&File")
        Action { text: qsTr("&New...") }

        Action {
            id: autoSaveAction
            checkable: true
            checked: true
            text: qsTr("&Auto Save")
            onToggled: autoSaveAction.checked = !autoSaveAction.checked
        }
    }
}
```

---

This is probably due to the fact that you would set a setting via the toggle signal and bind that setting to the `checked` property of the `MenuItem`/`Action` as it could be changed from somewhere else instead of binding to the `checked` state of a `MenuItem`/`Action`. Something like that:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    width: 320
    height: 260
    visible: true

    property bool autoSave: true

    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("&File")
            Action { text: qsTr("&New...") }

            Action {
                id: autoSaveAction
                checkable: true
                checked: window.autoSave
                text: qsTr("&Auto Save")
                onToggled: window.autoSave = !window.autoSave
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your second example works correctly in my case.